# Building FTP Client from Scratch: Error "425 Can't open data connection for transfer"

Tags: java, ftp, connection, port

I am trying to make an FTP client from scratch in Java.

I am using Filezilla as a server and I can connect to it up to a certain point. By that I mean that I have the Command port working, but no matter how much I search I cannot get the data port to connect.

All of the websites I've looked for say the problem has to do with the firewall and/or the router, however, when I try to connect to the server with the Filezilla client everything goes well.

What I have so far:

```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(20);
    socket = new Socket(127.0.0.1, 21);
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

    writer.write("USER " + Anonymous + "\n");
    writer.flush();
    writer.write("PASS " + "" + "\n");
    writer.flush();
    writer.write("PORT 127,0,0,1,0,14");
    writer.flush();
    writer.write("EPRT |1|127.0.0.1|20|");
    writer.flush()
    dataSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

That logs me into the server and disconnects. To fix that I added an infinte while loop inside a thread (for the time being) until I can connect to the data port.

Comment: There is no data port involved until you actually transfer a file.

Comment: Sounds like you need to (re-)read the RFC.

Comment: @immibis Ok, so i addedd a command to store a test.txt file. What do i do after that? It keeps giving me the error (I'm trying to use a server sockets that waits for a connection from the server, but i get the error before i even get to that)

Comment: If you change your code you will need to keep it up to date here, otherwise nobody knows what you're talking about. And don't just say 'the error'. Post it. Paste it. Into your question.

Comment: @EJP ok, i updated it. Sorry about the confusion, I created an account just to ask this question. The error that I keep getting is a message from the server when i try to do anything that involves the data port "425 Can't open data connection for transfer.”

Answer (score 1):

While you do an accept on the (presumably) data socket `socket2` you don't tell the server where this socket can be found, e.g. you did not issue a `PORT` or `EPRT` command before. Please have a deep look into the protocol documentation (mostly RFC959) before you attempt to implement the protocol.

Comment: The server log says that both of the new commands were successful but the client still gets stuck waiting for a connection at 'dataSocket.accpet()'. Am I suposed to put the commands in a different order? What shouls i be looking for in the RFC959? I tried looking for the errer 425 described in the title, but it wasnt very useful information.

Comment: Please please read the documentation and don't just issue two commands which you've seen somewhere. The ports you tell the server must reflect the actual ports you use (in this case 50222) not just something you just made up.

Answer (score 0):

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50222);
```

This creates a listening socket on port 50222.

```
writer.write("PORT 127,0,0,1,0,14");
```

This tells the server to connect to you on port 14.

Think about it.

Comment: Actually, the last two numbers are supposed to be hexadecimal. I put 14 because 14 in hexadecimal is 20 in decimal. You are right that i didn't have the right port there, its supposed to be 'serverSocket = new ServerSocket(20);' But even with that, it still wont connect. I am reading the RFC959 so hopefully i'll come up with the solution that way

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that the server was trying to connect to a port and it wasn't the right one. What i decided to do was put the server in passive mode and connect to the socket that I saw. When it responded with this"227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,194,16). The last two numbers are the port number. You have to turn to these decimals to hex and then take both hex numbers together to get the whole port number. On this case specifically 194 in decimal is equal to "C2" in hex, and 16 in decimal is equal to "10" in hex, with those two hex numbers combined you get "C210" which when you turn them back to decimal you get "49680" and that's the port number that you have to connect to.

```
  clientSocket = new Socket(127.0.0.1, 21);
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

  writer.write("USER " + Anonymous + "\n");
  writer.flush();
  writer.write("PASS " + "" + "\n");
  writer.flush();
  writer.write("PASV");
  writer.flush()
  String testPort = scanner.nextLine(); //type in the number you get when you do math
                                        //in this case 49680
  socketServer = new Socket(host, Integer.parseInt(testPort));
```

That should connect the data port. Obviously this is not the final program, but its a proof of concept. Thank you for the people that helped out.

Comment: 194*256+16=49680 might be easier than converting to hex, concatenate and re-convert.